# Text Based User Interface

Tags: text, interface

I work in a corporate office environment which routinely uses an IBM Mainframe and AS\400 as the main source of the Information System.

However, the company is growing faster than the information technology group can support.

Therefore, it is necessary to create ancillary applications to accommodate the ever changing business needs and new ventures.

I’ve introduced a web based application using PHP and MySql database (as we have routinely received bulk Mainframe downloads and imported into Microsoft Access Databases before upsizing the databases to a SQL server due to their ever increasing size).

It was been mandated that all new application be similar to look and functionality as the Mainframe. It must be a text based user interface where it’s not necessary to use the mouse, only function keys to navigate menus and pressing the enter key to add new data (records) or to execute a search.

What modern day programming language will satisfy this Text-based user interface mandate? Preferably something that can interact with MySql to fetch/store data and look similar to the mainframe and possibly support XML formatting (font colors, input fields, etc).

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You can build this in pretty much any language. Almost all programming languages have support for these things. Choose a modern language that your development team already knows well and use that. Ideally, it would be a high level language (don't use C) to speed up development time.

Answer (score 0):

its been a while since i have used it but ncurses might be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Java, Delphi, Visual Studio, etc, etc, etc. As @Oleksi said; pretty much any modern fat-client GUI language that has a database library that can handle MySQL will do.

If you're not sure which to use, you should either hire someone with experience or try a few small prototypes.